# Google App Engine Appstats

Tags: python, google-app-engine, appstats

Is it possible to use the data provided by Appstats inside my code?
I want to get the RPC Total and Grand Total values of each of my task.
Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's certainly possible, but you'll need to reach into the innards of appstats to do so - see [the source code](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse#svn%2Ftrunk%2Fpython%2Fgoogle%2Fappengine%2Fext%2Fappstats). It's probably not a good idea, though. If you need these measurements, you should probably learn from the appstats source and instrument your code yourself.